# How to set dynamic options from API response in fluent ui react Dropdown control?

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react, fluentui-react

I have encountered a situation where I need to display a Dropdown and want the options to dynamically fetch from an API and load on clicking the caret (maybe show a loader by the time the API response comes through). The experience I am looking for is something in the following lines -

[image]

Loading (fetching options from API)

[image]

Display options after successful response

The documentation didn't give any API surface through which this can be possible.
Is it possible to achieve this with the current APIs that are in place for this control component?

Answer (score 0):

Good point to start is to use `BasePicker Component` from `Pickers`.

```
import { BasePicker } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Pickers'
```

Inside `BasePicker` you have a methods which you can use to make a "lazy" behavior. For example, when you click on component then make a call to API and populate items list.

What is inside `BasePicker` take a look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/react-internal/src/components/pickers/BasePicker.types.ts) or from [official documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui/#/controls/web/pickers#IBasePickerProps).

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/BvOojj)